# Redux Form: Is it possible to access formReducer

Tags: javascript, redux-form

What I've been trying is t get a value from `formReducer` in a container component.

There are two component. One is a presentational component with `Redux-Form`.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="title"
                   component="input"
                    type="text"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

Form = reduxForm({
    form: 'PostEditor',
    enableReinitialize: true,
})(Form);

Form = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: state.post.post,
        enableReinitialize: true,
    }),
)(Form)

export default Form;
```

And the other is its container, which is where I'd like to access `formReducer`.

```
class PostEditor extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("form", this.props.PostEditor);//This results in "undefined"
        return (<Form onSubmit={data=> this.handleSubmit(data)}/>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        PostEditor: state.form
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PostEditor);
```

In Redux' store, form reducer is set to be `state.form`, but this cannot be accessed.

Is it possible to get values from the reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use one of ReduxForm selectors.

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        PostEditor: getFormValues('PostEditor')(state)
    }
}
```

Here you have detailed documentation: https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/selectors.md/

Answer (score 1):

To access the values of a form import the following selector from redux-form

```
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
```

Then call the function with the name of the form you wish to retrieve the values of in mapStateToProps.

This will return a function which is then called with the state of the Redux store as well as the name of the field for which we wish to obtain the value.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        titleFieldValue: formValueSelector('PostEditor')(state, 'title')
    }
}
```

We can also add in more arguments to this function call if we wish to retrieve multiple fields. For example

```
formValueSelector('PostEditor')(state, 'title', 'name', 'otherField')
```

The following syntax is an example of a "curried" function. This is just a name given to functions that return other functions. If you are interested read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) for an introduction to currying.